# spring-amqp not work correctly when connections are blocked

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, amqp, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I am using spring-amqp 1.4.4 and after queue contains too much messages and it is above watermark memory, RabbitTemplate receive method don't response if it was called after send method. It is wait indefinitely. And in spring xml I set reply-timeout="10" to rabbit:template. If i not call send method and simply call receive it work good. What's wrong?

```
template.convertAndSend("test message");

String msg = (String) template.receiveAndConvert("log.queue"); // receiveAndConvert not response
```

Answer (score 3):

The rabbitmq guys recommend using separate connections for publishers and consumers, for exactly this reason.

The spring amqp `CachingConnectionFactory` shares a single connection for all users.

We are looking at providing an option to use two connections but, in the meantime, you can configure two connection factories (and templates), one for sends and the other for receives.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I created two templates and now i got other problem - send method stop response after some high load and memory exceed watermark. When debug amqp-client code, problem was at SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame() during new connection or new channel creating. What's wrong now? in config requested-heartbeat="3000" connection-timeout="10"

Comment: SocketFrameHandler.writeFrame() method code is locked on synchronized and not continued:
synchronized (_outputStream) {
            frame.writeTo(_outputStream);
}

Comment: Either upgrade to a newer version, or increase the channel cache size in the connection factory, to avoid churning channels; with older versions of Spring AMQP, only one channel is cached. Starting with version 1.6 (current version is 1.6.5) we cache up to 25 channels by default; you should make sure the cache is large enough that you are not creating/closing channels at a high rate. Since channels are only used for a short time, a large cache is not generally required but 1 is generally insufficient when under high load.

Comment: After some experiences I think java amqp client not work normally under high load. Expecially if rabbit have not enough memory for work and it start to block channels. In that case java client blocks threads and waits infinitely long despite the timeouts.

Comment: Try using the new 4.1.0 version of `com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:4.1.0` - they have added a new timeout to avoid these hangs.